# Reference: Subalgebras of compact lie algberas

Tags: lie-algebras

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a simple, compact Lie algebra, plenty is known about its subalgebras:

- They're all reductive.
- Any simple subalgebra is also compact, and these are in 1 to 1 correspondence with the simple subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}^\mathbb{C}$.
- Any abelian subalgebra is contained in a Cartan subalgebra (being that it's an abelian algebra containing only semisimple elements).

What I can't seem to find, however, is an explicit description of what such subalgebras look like. Simple subalgebras can embed in pretty unpleasant ways (for example, in the case of S-subalgebras), and this affects what abelian subalgebras can commute with such a subalgebra.

Has anyone come across such a description?

Comment: For subalgebras of maximal rank this is the [Borel-de Siebenthal theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–de_Siebenthal_theory), and it is already quite involved.

Comment: Thank you @abx . It seems like this is mainly complicated because it's dealing with constructing the semisimple part. I'm more wondering about if anything has been written about the interaction between the semisimple part and the radical in terms of giving an explicit description of the radical in terms of the roots that appear in the semisimple part.